# how to load an App open ad when the app again resume from the background?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to show and *App open Ad* when the app again resume from the background but the ad is not showing. Please solve this issue in this page.To show an *AppOpenAd* when your Flutter app moves from the background to the resumed state using **google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0s** . Perform all code in this page and the ad show on **BottomNavigationPAge()**, the *AppOpenAd* is show only for the first time . Thank you in Advance.

```
  class AppLifecycleReactor {
      final AppOpenAdManager appOpenAdManager;
      AppLifecycleReactor({required this.appOpenAdManager});
      void listenToAppStateChanges() {
        AppStateEventNotifier.startListening();
        AppStateEventNotifier.appStateStream
            .forEach((state) => _onAppStateChanged(state));
      }
      void _onAppStateChanged(AppState appState) {
        if (appState == AppState.foreground ){
          appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable();
          appOpenAdManager.loadAppOpenAd();
        }
      }
    }
    class AppOpenAdManager {
      AppOpenAd? appOpenAd;
    
      loadAppOpenAd() {
        AppOpenAd.load(
          adUnitId: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294",
          request: const AdRequest(),
          adLoadCallback: AppOpenAdLoadCallback(
            onAdLoaded: (ad) {
              appOpenAd = ad;
              appOpenAd!.show();
              },
            onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {
              print(error);
            },
          ),
          orientation: AppOpenAd.orientationPortrait,
        );
      }
      void showAdIfAvailable() {
        if (appOpenAd != null) {
          appOpenAd!.show();
        }
      }
    }
    
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      MobileAds.instance.initialize();
      AppOpenAdManager();
      final cameras = await availableCameras();
      final firstCamera = cameras.first;
      bool beepChecked = true;
      final appOpenAdManager = AppOpenAdManager();
      appOpenAdManager.loadAppOpenAd();
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final bool shown = prefs.getBool('carouselShown') ?? false;
      final String initialRoute = shown ? '/' : '/carousel';
    
      runApp(
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => SettingsProvider(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: "QR Code Scanner",
            theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue.shade300),
            // home: initialRouteWidget,
            initialRoute: initialRoute,
            routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
              '/': (BuildContext context) => const BottomNavigationBarPage(),
              '/carousel': (BuildContext context) => CarouselWithBackground(
                onCarouselCompleted: () async {
                  // Mark the carousel as shown when it is completed
                  await prefs.setBool('carouselShown', true);
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
                },
              ),
              '/TakePictureScreen': (BuildContext context) =>
                  TakePictureScreen(camera: firstCamera),
              '/about': (BuildContext context) => AboutPage(),
              '/rate': (BuildContext context) => RateUsPage(),
              '/feedback': (BuildContext context) => FeedbackPage(),
              '/drawer': (BuildContext context) => SideMenuDrawer(),
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```